# Adding custom variable to paypal parallel payments IPN PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Hello i'm trying to implement the PAYPAL PARALLEL API, and i'm trying to pass a custom variable to paypal IPN
this my PHP code, its working without the custom variable, and i don"t know where to add this custom field:

```
$apiUrl = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/";
$paypalUrl = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=";

$headers = array(
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID : ".$paypal_user_id,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD : ".$paypal_pass,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE : ".$paypal_user_signature,
    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID : ".$paypal_app_id,
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT : JSON",
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT : JSON"
);

// curl wrapper for sending thhings to paypal
function paypalSend($data,$call){
    global $apiUrl;
    global $headers;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $apiUrl.$call);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    return json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
}

//create the pay request
$createPacket = array(
    "actionType"=>"PAY",
    "currencyCode"=>"USD",
    "receiverList"=> array(
        "receiver" => array(
            array(
                "amount" => $amount,
                "email" => $email
            )
        )
    ),
    "returnUrl" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/finish_withdraw.php",
    "cancelUrl" => "http://www.mywebsite.com/cancel_withdraw.php",

    "requestEnvelope"=> array(
        "errorLanguage"=>"en_US",    // Language used to display errors
        "detailLevel"=>"ReturnAll"
    )
);

$response = paypalSend($createPacket, "Pay");

$payKey = $response['payKey'];
$paymentExecStatus = $response['paymentExecStatus'];

$detailPacket = array(
    "requestEnvelope"=> array(
        "errorLanguage"=>"en_US",    // Language used to display errors
        "detailLevel"=>"ReturnAll"
    ),
    "payKey" => $payKey,
    "receiverOptions" => array(
        array(
            "receiver"=> array("email" => $email),
            "invoiceData" => array(
                "item" => array(
                    array(
                        "name" => "product 1",
                        "price" => $amount,
                        "identifier" => "p1"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

$response = paypalSend($detailPacket, "SetPaymentOptions");

//Wrapper to get payent details
$packet = array(
    "requestEnvelope"=> array(
        "errorLanguage"=>"en_US",    // Language used to display errors
        "detailLevel"=>"ReturnAll"
    ),
    "payKey" => $payKey,
);

$dets = paypalSend($packet, "GetPaymentOptions");

header('location: '.$paypalUrl.$payKey);
```

Comment: Tell me more about what what kind of custom data you want to send, and how you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ^^ , what i attempt to send is a variable that contains the user's id that performs the payment, this id i can get it from my database, and i want to receive this id in the ipn notification in order to insert this payment in my database, and link the payment with the specific user by his Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless paypal fixed something in the last 3 years, the ONLY way I could accomplish this was to send hyphenated data as the item_number

```
"item_number1": "t-253-22768-",
```

This format was "type" - "product id" - "user id" - "discount code"

Answer (score 2):

I believe I found the answer to your question on the following site:

https://enjoysmile.com/paypal-adaptive-payment-ipn-with-custom-variables/

Just add the variables you want on the IPN URL.
Example: (after the "cancel URL" add the following code)
"ipnNotificationUrl" => "http://www.example.com/paypal_ipn.php?custom1=1&custom2=2',

If you check the IPN message you receive this values on the "ipn_notification_url" value.

Hope this helps.